# RegExp.Test() always returning false

Tags: javascript, regex

I can't figure out why this is going wrong, but it always returns false for the test.

Anyone know what the problem?

[image]

Comment: Try with `\\.` instead of `\.`

Comment: First of all, please go read [ask]. Code necessary to reproduce your problem belongs directly into your question - not just as an image, not just dumped on an external site.

Comment: @Randy0111 Should we just *guess* the value of `adjVal`?

Comment: This problem has been resolved,thank you!

Answer (score 0):

'.' has a special meaning in regexp (and also ?[]+-*() as you may know), so you need to escape it with a back-slash.

However, the backslash being in a string, you have do double-escape it so that the JS parser "keeps it" in the regexp pattern

Comment: I suggested the same, but i think it isn't the problem, since the part with the dot is optional

Comment: I'm still sleeping this morning and mixed one post with another... Corrected mistake in first post. And going back to bed ;-)